# How to operate on a reader within a pipe?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I am trying to implement a reader. I have the following code (from Advent of Code 2023 day 2):

```
import * as A from "fp-ts/Array";
import * as Rc from "fp-ts/Record";
import * as Rd from "fp-ts/Reader";
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/function";

type Set = Record<string, number>;

type Game = {
  number: number;
  sets: Array<Set>;
};

const availableCubes: Set = {
  red: 12,
  green: 13,
  blue: 14,
};

function validateSet(set: Set): Rd.Reader<Set, boolean> {
  function res(availableCubes: Set): boolean {
    return pipe(
      set,
      Rc.keys,
      A.map((k) => set[k] < availableCubes[k]),
      A.every((x) => x)
    );
  }
  return res;
}

function validateGame(game: Game): Rd.Reader<Set, boolean> {
  const res = pipe(
    game,
    (x) => x.sets,
    A.map((x) => validateSet(x)),
    A.every((x) => x)
  );
  return res;
}
```

`validateSet` takes a `Set` and returns a `Reader<Set, boolean>` where the `Set` is the dependency `availableCubes` and the bool represents the validity of the set.

`validateGame` validates each set in the game by mapping over the array of sets with `validateSet` and checking that they are all true.

My problem is that `validateSet` returns a `Reader`, not a bool. So validateGame will not compile because of the following line, which treats as x a bool.

```
    A.every((x) => x)
```

How can I change my code so that I can perform the above operation where x is a `Reader<Set, bool>` and not a bool?

Comment: What's the point of using the Reader here? I'm not familiar with this fp-ts library, but it seems odd to use `.map()` followed by `.every()` as separate calls. Can't you use a single `.every(validateSet)`? Doing so isn't just less coding work and easier to understand, it also supports early bailout, so you don't have to waste time processing data when you've already seen a false.